# select group by count

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have two tables with the following schema

```
files
------
id
name
```

the second table

```
permission
-----------
id
file_id
downloads
code
```

now i need to select the top five downloaded files from the downloads table, noting that a `file_id` can appear many times because of the download code `code`

this is what i have

```
Select
  files.name,
  permission.downloads
From
  files Inner Join
  permission On permission.file_id = files.id
Order By
  permission.downloads Desc
Limit 5
```

thi select the top five as i needed, but repeats the file names, is there anyway i can sum the download count for each file so no filename is repeated

Comment: You'll want to read up on GROUP BY and aggregate functions: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use group by

```
select
  f.name,
  sum(p.downloads) as downloads
from files as f
  inner join permission as p on p.file_id = f.id
group by f.name
order By sum(p.downloads) desc
limit 5
```